# checking to see if Stream inputStream File exists or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am changing a method that used to accept string for temp folder and string for file and changing it to a stream and i wanted some help how to check if file exists or not.

```
bool UploadFile(Stream inputStream, Stream inputFile);
```

This is what i originally had and i want to change so the parameters accepts a stream

```
bool UploadFile(string tempFolder, string fileName)

public bool UploadFile(string tempFolder, string fileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                testingUsage.Upload(tempFolder, fileName);  
                return testingUsage.Exists(tempFolder);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

do i create two streams one for the file and one for location?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve... why would you have two streams? What is "testingUsage"?

Comment: Is the inputStream Stream coming from you inputFile and the inputFile Stream the stream of the file you want to write ?

Comment: I would imagine the file exist if you were able to have an active Stream in the first place.

Comment: Location is not a stream. So, you don't need a stream for your location. Also, how are you uploading your file? Most likely, you don't need a Stream for that either. Can you post your entire Action?

Comment: @ataravati i basically need to change the parameters to a accept a stream or a filestream instead of a string that is the main purpose. So should there be a stream for fileName and the tempFolder i would either have it defined within? I haven't used Stream before so if my question isn't super clear its because i am not sure to it could do to ask specifically about.

Comment: As I said, you don't need a Stream for the tempFolder, but I can't help you better unless I can see more code. That's why I asked you to post the entire Action code.

Comment: @ataravati at this point there is not action i am writing this along with test class to test functionality which is calling a library to do the actual upload. I have to change the upload method from string parameter to stream and the code that is required is above. the bool statement and the method below it.

Comment: Well, it seems like you are using the wrong term. Your function does not upload the file. It saves the uploaded file to a location. Also, you "upload" (save) the file only if the file exists? Please explain exactly what your method needs to do.

Comment: @ataravati so i have a file that has been uploaded and with this method i am taking this uploaded file and saving/uploading another copy of it in a different location.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your Upload Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            string tempFolder = "...";
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if(UploadFile(tempFolder, file))
            {
              // Return a View to show a message that file was successfully uploaded...
              return View();
            }   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Handle the exception here...
    }
}
```

Your Method can be something like this:

```
private bool UploadFile(string tempFolder, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   var path = Path.Combine(tempFolder, file.FileName);

   // if the file does not exist, save it.
   if (!File.Exists(path))
   {
      file.SaveAs(path);
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't even need a method for saving the file, you can save it inside your Action, unless you want to do some other stuff in the UploadFile method as well.